# Product details page showing blank

Tags: php, html, magento

The problem is my product does show up in categories but when I click on a product it gives me no details. The header, the footer everything is still there just the block for the product image and details is not displayed. I tried turning on logging and setting developer mode to check for errors but I didn't get any errors. Also I tried dumping the products array onto the page to make sure magento is able to retrieve it and it is dumping the array. I used the following line:

```
var_dump($_product->toArray());
```

I don't understand what the problem is

Comment: I think the issue is missing template for product detail page. You can follow this QA: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3201/product-page-is-blank-pointing-to-non-existant-template-frontend-base-default-te

Comment: its a php fatal error..try to debug

Comment: How do I go ahead debugging.

Comment: Also I forgot to add the product details page works fine for products I added a few months ago. This issue is only for products that I am adding now

Comment: you are using any custom theme? if you are using any custom theme then try to copy catalog.xml from base to your custom theme to check is there any problem with xml or not